# glShaderSource with length set to 0

Tags: c, opengl

I'm wondering wether the behavior of glShaderSource in this edge case is correct or not:

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const char**)ptr, length)
```

where:

```
char * tmp = (char*)alloca(0);
const char ** ptr = &tmp;
GLint length[1] = { 0 };
```

So basically OpenGL is told to read a zero length string, but it still calls strlen on it, even if it knows its length. In the spec it says that OpenGL will assume that the string is zero terminated only if we pass NULL as the 4th argument or the given lengths are lower than 0. Why is strlen called? Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: A zero length c-string has an actual length of 1 byte, so you should be using alloca(1)

Comment: @bcrist: the lenght the GL expects here is the number of crachters without the string termination marker.

Comment: ah, then yes that might be a bug in your driver's impl

Comment: yes, it seems like your driver is not conforming to the spec.  Is there a reason why you need to support non-zero-terminated strings?  In general its a good idea to always require strings to be null terminated, since this type of bug can be easy miss when testing libraries, etc.

Comment: In the Haskell OpenGL bindings, if you read an empty file you get an empty ByteString. If you pass that ByteString to OpenGL, alloca gets called with 0 length and the pointer gets passed to glShaderSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two situations where the OpenGL driver is allowed to assume that the shader data is null terminated, as given in the OpenGL 4 reference pages.

**From [glShaderSource](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glShaderSource.xml) Documentation:**

> **If `length` is `NULL`, each string is assumed to be null terminated**.
>   If `length` is a value other than `NULL`, it points to an array containing
>   a string length for each of the corresponding elements of `string`. Each
>   element in the length array may contain the length of the corresponding
>   string (the null character is not counted as part of the string length)
>   or **a value less than 0 to indicate that the string is null terminated**.
>   The source code strings are not scanned or parsed at this time; they are
>   simply copied into the specified shader object.

Since neither of emphasized constraints holds for the situation posed, the driver is not allowed to use unsafe c-string functions like `strlen` directly on the data provided.  If it did, it would likely run off past the end of the data and probably eventually access unallocated memory, crashing the program.

However, the driver *is* allowed to make a copy of the data into a safe buffer and then call `strlen` on that.  For example an implementation might contain code like this:

```
void glShaderSource(GLuint shader,
                    GLsizei count,
                    const GLchar **string,
                    const GLint *length)
{
    if (length == NULL) { /* each string is null terminated. */ }
    else for (GLsizei i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        size_t len = length[i];

        if (len < 0) { /* this string is null terminated. */ }
        else
        {
            char* buffer = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
            memcpy(buffer, string[i], len);
            buffer[len] = 0;

            size_t str_len = strlen(buffer);
            // This is OK, because we copied the
            // data into a null terminated buffer.

            free(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

So if your driver is actually calling `strlen` on the user provided pointer in this case, then it is in violation of the OpenGL spec, and liable to cause program crashes, but merely seeing that `strlen` is being called by `glShaderSource` does not necessarily mean that it is one of the user-provided strings being passed to it.

On a slightly tangential note, what happens when a null character is present inside a string which is provided with an explicit length is not specified by the standard, which means an implementation may do as it likes.  It could treat the string as null terminated (thus skipping everything after it), ignore the null character, or or cause the compilation of the shader to fail since it is not among the characters recognized by GLSL as whitespace.